# What should I do if a new cabinet is smaller than the old one?

Tags: flooring, floor, tiling

I want to change my bathroom cabinets, but need ideas for floor. If I leave the same tile and the new cabinet footprint doesn't match the old, then there will be a portion of the floor exposed with no tile.  What can I do to fill the gap?

Comment: Add more tile. There's nothing else really. I always advice people to finish the entire floor, then add cabinets on top for exactly this reason.

Comment: How big is the space between the new cabinet and the tile?

Answer (score 3):

Some generic pieces of advice here:

1. Buy cabinets with a bigger footprint.
2. If a smaller footprint it can work out if there is an equal distance around the bottom.  You can lay down mosaics to make a border.  It really depends and we would need to see a picture for more help.
3. Anytime you tile a bathroom, tile the whole thing.  Cabinets should sit on the tile.

Comment: @mikeytown2 - in most cases it is easier too.